# Какой выбрать LInux-дистрибутив для компьютера с нестабильным питанием?

Tags: linux

Есть компьютер (1 ядро, 2Гб оперативы), который живет в частном секторе с достаточно нестабильным электричеством. На нем сейчас стоит WinXP. Но из-за частых колебаний напряжения вылетает загрузчик ОС. Выглядит это как постоянная перезагрузка. После ручного восстановления (копирование файлов ОС с дистрибутива на флешке) работоспособность восстанавливается на некоторое время. Возникла мысль поставить другую ОСь, чтобы не так быстро все слетало. Win7 вроде должна быть постабильней, но меня пугает недостаток ресурса для обслуживания ОСи. Возникла мысль о Linux. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как-нибудь дистрибутив, который будет более-менее стабилен в таких условиях эксплуатации и будет достаточно дружелюбен к пользователю, т.к. пользователи сего агрегата - пожилые люди.

**З.Ы.** упреждая возможные вопросы, бесперебойник имеется, но он триггерный и, по наблюдениям, не успевает сработать предварительно перед скачком, т.е. пропускает скачек напряжения, а потом переключается. Этого уже достаточно, чтобы комп потух.

**З.З.Ы.** машиной предполагается пользоваться в слабом пользовательском режиме. Основная задача - скайп несколько раз в неделю, серфинг новостных сайтов, игры типа "Паук", "Косынка" и т.п.

Comment: 2 гб вполне хватает для 7. Попробуй отключить восстановление при загрузке. На крайний случай Windows 7 PE с флешки загружаться и флешку в автозагрузку.

Comment: xubuntu, lubuntu lts amd64. russian fedora тоже неплохо.

Comment: тут вопрос не в оси а скорее в файловой системе. под виндой должна быть NTFS. FAT не любит сбоев. Под linux не ниже ext3, а дистрибутив какой больше понравится. Для надежности можно корень вообще в read only держать, тогда проблемы с загрузкой могут возникнуть только из за серьезного повреждения /var а его копию можно где то хранить и на случай проблем сделать скрипт который его развернет

Comment: @Mike, какой нафиг Linux?! Если человеку нужен skype, то это на 99% нужна Windows.

Comment: А машина (процессор) 32 бита или 64?

Comment: @0andriy А у skype какие то проблемы под linux ? вот вижу на официальном сайте есть дистрибутив skype, пакеты по крайней мере для двух дистрибутивов: https://www.skype.com/ru/download-skype/skype-for-linux/

Comment: @Mike, на 32-битных машинах Skype всё. Читайте пресс-релиз Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал при установке Linux (неважно, какой дистрибутив, дело, как уже сказали в комментариях, в файловых системах) сделать следующее:

1. Сделать / насколько возможно маленьким (600 мегабайт должно быть достаточно, если всё сделано правильно), вынеся с него /usr, /usr/local, /var, /home, /tmp, /opt и /boot на отдельные разделы.
2. После окончания установки перемонтировать /boot в R/O (это потребует обратного перемонтирования в R/W перед обновлениями системы) или хотя бы в sync.
3. Перемонтировать / в sync mode (это БУДЕТ тормозить операции записи в корневую файловую систему, отсюда п.1)
4. Использовать XFS везде, кроме /tmp (там можно ext2).

Comment: а есть какой-то источник, где описываются, хотя бы примерно, эти действия? ) Я не такой уж спец в Linux :(

Comment: Никакого Linux  для старых машин не получится держать из-за skype.